# DataTable to ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, datatable, arraylist

I want to get value from datatable and then store it to the string() arraylist. datatable contain 3 column (columnA | columnB | columnC). I want to get all value from columnB and store it to arraylist.

I have try something like this

```
If myTableData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To myTableData.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim value() As String = myTableData.Rows(i)(1)
    Next
End If
```

but when I compile that code, I got error message like this :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'

please help me.....

Comment: What framework-version do you have? And what do you mean by "want to get all value from rowB and store it to the rowB"? That sounds ridiculous since rowB already contains all values of rowB.

Comment: sorry my fault.
I have edit my question

Comment: Check myTableData.Rows(i)(1) must be returning String Array, you are assigning it to String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim a() As String
Dim total As Integer

'Count the number of rows
    total = myTableData.Rows.Count - 1

ReDim a(0 To total)
    For i = 0 To total
        a(i) = myTableData.Rows(i)(1)
    Next
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do that with LINQ:

```
Dim colBValues = (From row In myTableData Select colB = row(1).ToString).ToList
```

Or if you prefer the "old-school" way:

```
Dim colBValues = New List(Of String)
For Each row As DataRow In myTableData.Rows
    colBValues.Add(row(1).ToString)
Next
```

I've used a `List(Of String)` because it's type-safe, therefore you don't need to cast the values everytime. That makes code more readable, more failsafe and faster.

If you need it as String-Array, you could simply use [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx):

```
Dim colBValues = (From row In myTableData Select colB = row(1).ToString).ToArray
```

- [List(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx)

Comment: Thank's for your help. anyway, I like the way you call it "old-school way"   :D. I just started using VB.Net. I think must learn more about LINQ

Comment: @Flashidkz: If you need a String-Array, you could also use the [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) on the LINQ-Query.(edited my answer)

Comment: @Flashidkz: As a final side-note, you should stay away from arrays as your default collection type. They are out-of-date already. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: @Flashidkz if you just started, then learning the old school way is the way to go in my opinion. Then check out LINQ. At least you'll know how to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is really old question, but I'll provide one more variant of answer :

```
Dim value = myTableData.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).Select(Function(x) x(1).ToString()).ToArray
```

So, if You have more than one `column` in Your `DataTable` You can use `x(columnIndex)` instead 1.

Comment: Thats my prefered method too.